# How to Control/Invoke a method of some running instance from "outside" at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I Have many Foo.exe running, and I want to invoke some Foo methods on specific instances (Foo_1.DoStuff() ) via an external controller (Bar.exe)
Bar should be able to see any Foo.exe running and interact with each one.
What would be the best/simplest techno/architecture to achieve this ?
I thought of WCF but I faced some limitations (I do not need a service per se, I need Foo to expose some interfaces invokable at runtime) but maybe this was due to my average mastering of this technology.

PS : Just for information, this is a synthetic/general version of a more specific/detailed question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895643/callback-a-dll-from-outside-via-a-wcf-service-or-other)

EDIT : Using a [Self-Hosted Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) properly did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way of interprocess communication. That can be easily done with WCF or .NET Remoting.

Comment: "easily" is a relative adjective : I have been tweaking code for a couple of day now, with no really satisfying result. I guess I need some detailed code on a working example.

Comment: Another possibility that comes in my mind: You could open a socket and listen to a specified port. But however, in my project I have 3 Programs running. 1 Explorer Shell Extension, which communicates with another desktop application, and a windows service, which runs as the main WCF service host. And there really aren't any problems. Just expose an interface and start the host. Maybe in another thread if you don'want to block the main program (Works in my case)

Comment: Ok. WHat I do not understand is how to start a "Foo" instance, and make it host a service that would trigger a Foo method when it is called. I know how to do both separately (i.e implement and call a WCF service) but I failed into hosting that service into an independant class to expose methods of that executable class

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're confused with `host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FOO));` and dont know where to access the service's functions? If that's it what you need, then try making a singleton service object. That means, instead of `host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FOO));` you'll write `var svc = new FOO();` Do something with FOO, add delegates, etc.. and then create the host from FOO's instance `host = new ServiceHost(svc);`

Comment: Thanks to your advice and some external resources I solved my problem using a self-hosted service like described here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx